# GCE & Kubernetes : Is Service's ClusterIP fixed?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, kubernetes

When the service is created with `ClusterIP` Type, the cluster ip is fixed or it could be changed?

I wonder that because I want to access the ClusterIP via VPN from my own DC

If it is fixed, then the IP address can be configured in client directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the clusterIP to whatever you want when you create the service just by setting the `clusterIP` attribute in the service's spec.

I *think* you could also do the same thing once the service has been created, but it'd likely mess with any apps that were talking to it.